# OR logic in memcmp filter

Tags: anchor, memcmp

When fetching accounts with a filter, how can I build the filter so elements have a OR logic instead of a AND ?

```
let res = await program.account.gameAccount.all([
        {
            memcmp: {
                offset: 8 + 9, 
                bytes: address2,
            }
        },
       {
            memcmp: {
                offset: 8 + 9 + 32, 
                bytes: address2,
            }
        },

    ]);
```

Like, in this example, I want accounts that verify at least one of the two memcmp. As is it written right now, it gives accounts that verify both.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to do it one call, since the filters are always additive in `get_program_accounts`. For OR behavior, you'll need to make two separate calls.

More information on `get_program_accounts` at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getprogramaccounts